# calling react component function inside another react component function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, meteor, meteor-react

I am calling getReverseGeocodingData() from callback function of  getCurrentPosition. getting  the error below 
function is not defined?

```
getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                console.log(position.coords.longitude);

             getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                alert('Ahmad');
            });
        } else {
             console.error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }
    getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        // This is making the Geocode request
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                alert(status);
            }
            // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am using meteor with react , the above code is inside one of  react component 
I tried to call if with this keyword with parenthesis and without?

I tried the following options, but it didn't help
I am getting getReverseGeocodingData is not function!!
    this.getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude).bind(this);

```
getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude).bind(this);


this.getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude).bind();

this.getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

screenshot of console error

[image: screenshot of console error]

I updated the code as the below but I am still the issue below
Cannot read property 'getReverseGeocodingData' of undefined

```
export default class AddUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
            this.getReverseGeocodingData = this.getReverseGeocodingData.bind(this);
        }
        getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            // This is making the Geocode request
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert(status);
                }
                // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results);
                    var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
                }
            });
        }

        getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                    console.log(position.coords.longitude);

                    this.getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                });
            } else {
                console.error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
        }
```

added screenshot for last change.

[image]

The issue fixed by adding bind to the call inside the html.

[image]

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `this.getReverseGeocodingData(...)`. Also, you should explicitly bind `this` if you are passing `getLocation` to some other components (otherwise you will lose the `this` reference to the current component)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , please see my addtional information above :(

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found is to bind all of your functions needed in the constructor:

```
export default class AddUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getReverseGeocodingData = this.getReverseGeocodingData.bind(this);
    }

    someFunction() {
        this.getReverseGeocodingData(...)
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to bind `this` on every render.

Then you need to use an arrow function to maintain the scope of `this`:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    this.getReverseGeocodingData(...);
    ...
});
```

Comment: The fat arrow function inside `getCurrentPosition` is the key here.

Comment: I am getting new error with the above Cannot read property 'getReverseGeocodingData' of undefined  
please check my updted code

Comment: Is the error in the same spot it was before? Or are you using the 'getReverseGeocodingData' function elsewhere?

Comment: That looks right to me -- although one thing I omitted above (now fixed) is you should call `super(props)` as the first thing in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `this` keyword.

`this.getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);`